# Javascript - Track any xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, dom, xmlhttprequest

Can I check any XmlHttpRequest, executable on page without adding addEventListener each of it? I try add

```
document.addEventListener("loadend"...)
```

but nothing happend.
Looks like requests don't have a global events?

// EDITED //

I need detect new elements, which loaded by ajax. 
Great solution for it- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042483/4551767)

Using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should rethink your design. Why do you want to do this. Are there better options?

However if you really want to do this you could "hack" it by overwriting the standard `XmlHttpRequest` object with your own. You will have to do this before any `XmlHttpRequest` is initiated though to make it work for all objects.

```js
//store the original XMLHttpRequest in a variabele so you can use it yourself
var originalXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;

//Overwrite the original object with your own in which you create an instance of the original object, add an event listner to it and return that.
XMLHttpRequest = function() {
  var req = new originalXMLHttpRequest();
  req.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
    console.log("loadend event fired");
  });
  return req;
};

//Test if it works
httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpReq.open("GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/");
httpReq.send();
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. I write own css for android application web view by target site. Everything fine, but site can't have a classes or id or other things for css-selecting. So, all links just <a> :) And i use javascript for adding classes. But site have a ajax-loading new content, which i can't handle with my script, which start on page load complete.

Comment: You might want to look into the `MutationObserver` object. I think that would be a better tool for the job.

Comment: That exactly what is needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make your `XMLHttpRequest`s fire a custom event when they're done and then listen for those events.

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.onload = function() {
    e = new CustomEvent('myLoadend', {detail: {foo: 'bar'}});
    document.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

And listen to those events:

```
document.addEventListener("myLoadend"...)
```

Comment: I can't acces to original event.

Comment: Which original event? Maybe you mean the requests?

Comment: Yeah. I write code for android app, custom design for site. Can't change original css or js.