# Listen for API call successfully

Tags: javascript, api, https, addeventlistener

I want to run some JavaScript/DOM manipulation, only after an API call has been successful.

I have the following code... However, all its doing is checking the response of an API call.

What I need to do, is `listen out` for this API call being made successfully (Like an EventListener). As the API doesn't run immediately on pageload.  It only runs, after a user has submitted a form.

So I need to listen out for the API call, rather than run it instantly on pageload.

```
var testAPI = new XMLHttpRequest();
var testAPIurl='https://www.myapi.com/xxx';
testAPI.open("GET", testAPIurl);
testAPI.send();

testAPI.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(testAPI.responseText));

    var res = JSON.parse(testAPI.responseText);
    
    if (res.Status === "loggedIn") {
      console.log("USER LOGGED IN!");
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do this in vanilla JavaScript?

Thanks,

Comment: EventListeners call functions when something happens, in your case you can call a function when testAPI.onreadystatechange returns true, can't you just use that instead?

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)  is the documentation on how you can create your own custom events

Comment: @RicardoSanchez - Hey no this doesn't work.  If the page loads, then the user is not logged in.  And therefore, the function above is not true, (it's false).  Only once they log in, is the API call made.

So I want to listen out for the API call being made.

Comment: I see, the link on my second comment has instructions on how to create your own, then all you do is dispatch the event call whenever need it, hope that helps.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez- Thanks for this, but what would I run the event on?  The button click, or the document/window?

Comment: I have not implemented custom events myself, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041883/javascript-track-any-xmlhttprequest/55042483#55042483) may have your solution